# How to draw a 2D square with intersecting lines?

Tags: tkz-euclide, shapes

I'm trying to draw this exact image (attached)

Specific properties of the image:

```
  - angle QAP = 45 degrees (labeled theta)
  - ABCD is a square
  - P' is the 90 degree rotation of P along A (lying on CD)
  - Q and P can be anywhere in the lines BC and CD respectively 
  - AQ is the perpendicular bisector (cuts the middle) of line PP'
```

MANY Thank-you's for your help. Just recently starting learning this stuff.

[image]

Comment: You may be interested in `tkz-euclide` package.

Comment: I have removed the [geometry] tag, as that applies explicitly to the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all straightforward with the `calc` library, where you can retrieve the coordinates with the `let ... in` syntax and use e.g. `atan2` to compute angles and `veclen` to compute lengths that can be used in polar coordinates. In the following, `a` is the dimension of the square, and `b` the horizontal distance between Q and D.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=4;b=1;}]
 \draw (0,a) coordinate[label=above:$A$] (A) --
  (a,a) coordinate[label=above:$B$] (B) --
  (a,0) coordinate[label=below:$C$] (C) --
  (0,0) coordinate[label=below:$D$] (D) -- cycle;
 \path (b,0) coordinate[label=below:$Q$] (Q)
  let \p1=($(Q)-(A)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)+45} in
   ($(A)+(\n1:1)$) coordinate (aux) 
   (intersection cs:first line={(C)--(B)},second line={(A)--(aux)})
   coordinate[label=right:$P$] (P)
   let \p2=($(P)-(A)$),\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)-90},\n3={veclen(\x2,\y2)}
   in ($(A)+(\n2:\n3)$) coordinate[label=below:$P'$] (P');
 \draw [blue] (Q) -- (A) -- (P) -- (P');  
 \fill foreach \X in {A,B,C,D,P,P',Q} {(\X) circle[radius=1.5pt]  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you may vary b.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0.2,0.25,...,2,1.95,1.9,...,0.25}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=4;b=\X;}]
 \path[use as bounding box] (-a,-0.5) rectangle (a+0.5,a+0.5);
 \draw (0,a) coordinate[label=above:$A$] (A) --
  (a,a) coordinate[label=above:$B$] (B) --
  (a,0) coordinate[label=below:$C$] (C) --
  (0,0) coordinate[label=below:$D$] (D) -- cycle;
 \path (b,0) coordinate[label=below:$Q$] (Q)
  let \p1=($(Q)-(A)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)+45} in
   ($(A)+(\n1:1)$) coordinate (aux) 
   (intersection cs:first line={(C)--(B)},second line={(A)--(aux)})
   coordinate[label=right:$P$] (P)
   let \p2=($(P)-(A)$),\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)-90},\n3={veclen(\x2,\y2)}
   in ($(A)+(\n2:\n3)$) coordinate[label=below:$P'$] (P');
 \draw [blue] (Q) -- (A) -- (P) -- (P');  
 \fill foreach \X in {A,B,C,D,P,P',Q} {(\X) circle[radius=1.5pt]  };
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm completely new to overleaf. No coding experience or anything so I really appreciate your help here. I'll look into everything you mentioned to be able to make my own stuff. Thanks AGAIN for your amazing help it is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

With tkz-euclide v1.16 or 2.40 beta [here](http://altermundus.fr/files/euclide/geom_2.40b.zip)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmax = 8] 
  \tkzDefPoint(8,0){C}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){D}
  \tkzDefSquare(D,C)
  \tkzGetPoints{B}{A}
  \tkzDrawSquare(D,C)
  \tkzGetRandPointOn[segment = C--D]{Q}
  \tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center A angle 45](Q)
  \tkzGetPoint{p}
  \tkzInterLL(A,p)(C,B) \tkzGetPoint{P}
  \tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center A angle -90](P)
  \tkzGetPoint{P'}
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,Q,P,P')
  \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,D,Q,P,P')
  \tkzDrawSegments(A,Q A,P P,P' D,P')
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 1.5](Q,A,P){$45^{\circ}$}
  \tkzMarkAngle[size = 1.8,mark = none,arc=l](Q,A,P)
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]